# adding Indexed to Core Data property - when is it created? Will it break app update?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am releasing an update to my app and I Indexed a few fields in my model to speed up searching and lookups.

Is this going to break my update requiring a re-install?  Or will it be a smooth upgrade and those properties will just get indexed the next time the app is run?

I did not change the model in any other way.

Comment: did you add a new version of your datamodel? Or did you just change the old one?

Comment: if he change the old one - any presistend saved data will be not compatible. A new version would be a solution, but if he had versioning, he would not ask, right?

Comment: I can easily add versioning, that will solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will break. You changed the model after all.

Just change it and let it run in the simulator. it should throw you an exeption since they differ. You could use versioning, but that is a pain for a small change.

Comment: great free video that explains it a bit more in depth here: 
http://ideveloper.tv/store/details?product_code=10003

Answer (score -1):

Any time you change the model in any way at all, you need to use versioning to continue using existing data stores (like the ones that users already have in their copies of the app). For the changes you describe this should be quite simple-- you can use [automatic lightweight migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweight.html) and the updating should be automatic and quick.